# 'make: nothing to be done for p1 and' no rule to make target 'clean''

Tags: macos, terminal, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile titled 'p1' for a project.

When I try the command `make p1` it returns with `make: nothing to be done for p1`

Also, when I try the command `make p1 clean` it returns `no rule to make p1 'clean.' Stop`

Here is my makefile:

```
a.out: main.o P1LinkedList.o const_iterator.o iterator.o Node.o
        g++ -std=c++11 main.o const_iterator.o iterator.o Node.o

main.o:
        g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp

P1LinkedList.o:
        g++ -std=c++11 -c P1LinkedList.cpp

iterator.o:
        g++ -std=c++11 -c iterator.cpp

const_iterator.o:
        g++ -std=c++11 -c const_iterator.cpp

Node.o:
        g++ -std=c++11 -c Node.cpp

depend:
        g++ -MM main.cpp > p1.dep

clean:
        rm -f a.out *.o
```

What do I need to fix to have the makefile compile .o files from my .cpp files and how do I fix the issue with the clean command?

Edit: 
Here are the commands I've used to compile manually:

```
Helens-Air:p1a helenade$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp
Helens-Air:p1a helenade$ ./a.out
```

^^ and this just continues with the program execution from there

Comment: If the makefile is named `p1`, then instead of `make p1`, try `make -f p1`. If that works, we will have the problem half-solved.

Comment: @Beta that worked, but the compiler is now giving me the error `"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:..."`and then finally `"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"`  which I don't get when I just manually compile using `g++ -std=c++11.` My professor also said that the makefile has to use the command `make p1` so I can't use `-f` :(

Comment: Can you show the command you use when compile manually? I'll start writing an Answer.

Comment: I've posted my Answer, and I'll edit it to cover the other problems once you show me the command and maybe we do another experiment or two.

Comment: For `make p1` to work, your makefile has to be called `Makefile`, and in that file, there has to be a target named `p1`.

Answer (score 1):

We may have to take this in stages.

**First,** you seem to misunderstand the difference between a *makefile* name and a *target* name. This appears to have been a miscommunication between you and your teacher, but it's easy to clear up.

Suppose you have a makefile named "Makefile", containing the following:

```
foo:
    @echo running the foo rule

bar:
    @echo running the bar rule
```

If you `make foo`, you will get:

```
running the foo rule
```

The argument (`foo`) tells Make which target to attempt to build. And how did Make know which makefile to use? (After all, you could have a dozen makefiles in the working directory.) You can specify which makefile to use, but if you don't then by default Make will look for a makefile named `Makefile` (or `makefile` or `GNUmakefile`, don't worry about this for now). To specify a makefile with another name, like "Buildfile", you can use the `-f` flag:

```
make -f Buildfile
```

So "p1" ought to have been the name of a *target,* not a *makefile.* Within the makefile, rename your `a.out` rule to `p1`. Then rename the whole makefile to `Makefile`. Then

```
make p1
```

should work (or at least run).

**Edit:**

I'll go out on a limb. In the `a.out` rule (which should now be called the `p1` rule), I notice that you have left `P1LinkedList.o` out of the list of object files to be linked. So try changing it:

```
p1: main.o P1LinkedList.o const_iterator.o iterator.o Node.o
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o P1LinkedList.o const_iterator.o iterator.o Node.o
```

If that works, you can simplify it with an [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
p1: main.o P1LinkedList.o const_iterator.o iterator.o Node.o
    g++ -std=c++11 $^
```

And there will be other small improvements you can make.

If it *doesn't* work, try `ls *.cpp` and see if you've overlooked some *other* source file.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this solves a big chunk of the issues I've been having. I posted the commands I use when compiling/executing manually. I'm going to make some changes to my makefile with your answer and see where it gets me